# Background on the top and on the bottom

Tags: html, css

I've got some code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Container width is for example 900px.
At the #top i set a background using body.

But I can't use background in the #bottom becouse it will crashed when it will be wider eg 1080px(background will be seen only on the #container). How to do this?

## edit1:

```
body
{
background-image: url("images/bg_main.png");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
#top
{
    background-image: url("images/top_bg.png");
    height:50px;
}
#container
{
    margin: 0;
    width: 1024px;
    background:#fff;
}
#footer
{

    background-image:url("images/bottom.png")
}
```

but it creates inside container (i need to create bottom bg outside container, when site wiill be wider)

## edit2:

I think that I found an solution:
`html{;background-image:url('images/bottom.png');background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:left bottom;}`, and then set div height as a bottom.png

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? With the small snippet you have now, I wouldn't know what to say. For instance, what is "at the #top I set a background using body"?

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are trying to achieve... can you try and extend you question with more information?

Comment: It sounds like the problem he's having is that the background image in the #bottom div is getting cropped because it's limited to the same width as the container div (900px instead of 1080px). The easiest solution is to simply expand the width of #container to 1080px, is there a reason you can't do this?

Comment: I can't do this, becouse it have to be in 900px (it have to more space around).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>​
```

and with the addition of the following css:

```
#footer
{
    width:100%;
    height:40px; //Or something else you'd like
    background-color: yellow; //Or the image you want
}​
```

Comment: But I need to footer-content be at the same level of container.

Comment: I think that I found an solution: html{;background-image:url('images/bottom.png');background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:left bottom;}, and then set div height as a bottom.png

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "the same level". I think you mean that the footer-content must be inside of the container. If you mean this than the answer is that it is not possible. The footer will only get larger if the container gets larger (if width:100%). If you'd put the footer outside of the container it is (if width:100%) resized as the window resizes.

Comment: Reaction to your second comment: 
In that case I din't understand what you are going for. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I mean in the same position of container - becouse i want to add some text in the footer :) sorry for my english. I forget to add body margin 0 auto 0 auto in my pastebin :)

Comment: If you put the footer in the container you cant expect it to be as wide as the browser screen. Because the container is 1024px, the footer wil never be larger than the container it is in.

Comment: Yes but what about bg footer? :) bg footer have to be wider than footer in container, so i do it in html tag in css. It works as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try placing your `#bottom` outside `#container` than, because within `#container` you can't raise your width more than that of `#container`.
Try this:

```
#container{
  width:1024px; //or whatever
}
#bottom{
  height:40px; //or whatever
  width:100%; 
  background:url("images/bottom.png") repeat-x center;
}
```

Comment: This gives you a horizontal scrollbar if the browser is smaller than 1080px. Also the bottom will not go along if the browser is wider than 1080px. You should indeed place the bottom outside the container if you want this to be wider without the container going along. But this is not a generic sollution.

Comment: I think that I found an solution: html{;background-image:url('images/bottom.png');background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:left bottom;}, and then set div height as a bottom.png

Comment: @RickHoving : Thanks. See the edited code. will this be a solution?